# Which to choose between “that”, “if”, or “whether”?

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions

Which is correct?:

> Your question is very broad, and I doubt **that** it is answerable.
>
> Your question is very broad, and I doubt **if** it is answerable.
>
> Your question is very broad, and I doubt **whether** it is answerable.

Comment: I'd remove 'and' (or the comma) from all of them.

Comment: @mcalex. If you do that you create two clauses, which in writing would need to be separated by a period or a semi-colon.

Comment: ok, so rip out the comma.

Comment: @mcalex: If we're going for the "slash and burn" approach, let's just go the whole hog with [...I doubt it is answerable](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+doubt+it+is+possible%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Nothing wring with that, imho.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They all seem grammatical and reasonably idiomatic American English to me. It's a matter of style. I don't think any native speaker would have a problem understanding any of them, so I'd say that they're all "correct" in that sense.

"Correct" is a difficult word to define when it comes to English usage. If it's not ungrammatical, it may be **grammatically correct**, but it may not be something that a native speaker normally says, so then it wouldn't be **idiomatically correct**. Then, too, there's **technically correct** (the expected answers on internationally standardized English tests like the TOEFL and IELTS), and what your English teacher says is **correct** on his or her tests. I've seen myriad English tests in Taiwan and Japan, and most contain some multiple-choice questions that have no correct answers or many correct answers

I'd say and write #1, I wouldn't say or write #2, and if I were to use *whether*, I'd have to change "doubt" to "wonder". But, as I said above, it's strictly a matter of style in this case.

Comment: +1 for '"Correct" is a difficult word to define'.  I suspect most native speakers could understand "Is you is or is you ain't my baby?".

Comment: Most native speakers can also often understand various incorrect English spoken by foreigners, and word-for-word translations from other languages.

Answer (score 4):

You've brought up an interesting problem. The word *doubt*, when used as a verb, generally expresses uncertainty, along with a lack of assurance or confidence, as in:

> *I doubt we will win the game*.

Both *doubt* and *don't know* are ways to express uncertainty, but *doubt* connotes less confidence, while *don't know* suggests an inability to form a conclusion or hunch. In other words, if the weatherman says one of these two sentences:

> I doubt it will rain tomorrow.
>   I don't know if it will rain tomorrow.

then neither is conclusive, but I'm more inclined to leave my umbrella home in the first case, but to at least bring it in my car in the second.

So, going back to your example sentences, I'm not sure I would use any of them. If I had real *doubt* that the question was answerable, I'd be more inclined to say:

> *Your question is very broad; I doubt it is answerable.*

without putting any word between "doubt" and "it."

However, if I changed the verb to *don't know*, to express a higher level of uncertainty, I might use one of your options then:

> *Your question is very broad; I don't know if it's answerable.*
>   *Your question is very broad; I don't know whether it's answerable.*

Comment: Doubt (at least to me) has a negative connotation in some uses.  I have some foreign customers who react to some explanations by saying "We have some doubts".  It helped the interaction to realize that this was more "there are some things we don't understand" than "we don't believe you".

Comment: @Ross: _Doubt_ is a noun there, not a verb; I'd interpret such remarks to have one of two meanings: either (a) "We have some _misgivings_," or (b) "We are _skeptical_ about what you're saying." Although that would usually be construed as negative, there might be a few odd exceptions. For example, if a friend said, "I heard in a radio report that the Labor party was in trouble in the upcoming election," and I responded with, "Well, I have my doubts about that report," I could be expressing skepticism – but also a measure of optimism, depending on which side of the political spectrum I lean.

Comment: Is there any difference between "I doubt anyone slept that night," and "I doubt if anyone slept that night"?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I doubt that there's any difference in meaning between those. (It seems like you could use "that" in place of "it" as well.) [Cool Ngram on this](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+doubt+anyone%2CI+doubt+if+anyone%2CI+doubt+that+anyone&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Answer (score 2):

All three are grammatical, but as a speaker of British English, I would normally say the second. However, *doubt that* occurs much more frequently in the Corpus of Contemporary American English, the British National Corpus and in citations in the Oxford English Dictionary than either *doubt if* or *doubt whether*, but we need to aim off to some extent for the occasions on which *that* will be a demonstrative pronoun rather than a subordinator.

The choice between *if* and *whether* in general can sometimes involve ambiguities, but these are normally resolved in speech by intonation. In writing, however, the choice can make a difference to the meaning. If someone sends us an invitation which includes the words ‘Please let us know if you’re coming’, we may think that we need to indicate our intention only if we plan to accept the invitation. If we don’t, we might conclude, there is no need to say anything. The writer, however, may have intended to us to reply in either case, and the use of *whether* rather than *if* would have avoided that difficulty.

Comment: good point about if.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question. The first point to note is there's no absolute rule of grammar involved here. OP's sentence is perfectly valid with *that, if, whether*, or indeed, ***nothing at all*** between the verb *doubt* and the statement which is doubted. The second point to note is that [usage has changed](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20doubt%20there%20is,I%20doubt%20if%20there%20is,I%20doubt%20whether%20there%20is,I%20doubt%20that%20there%20is&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)...

[image]

From a quick glance, you might suppose that *"if"* is now the preferred [conjunction](http://www.eslincanada.com/english/englishlesson1.php), but focussing on [American](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20doubt%20there%20is,I%20doubt%20if%20there%20is,I%20doubt%20whether%20there%20is,I%20doubt%20that%20there%20is&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) usage over the last few decades (usually a good indicator of where English is going)...

...it seems "no conjunction at all" is making a comeback from its C18 heyday. Which accords with my own perception, and – dare I say it – seems like the sensible choice. Why give yourself the problem of choosing between the other three possibilities, if you don't need to use any of them?

[image]

In case it's not obvious, the third point to make is that none of the variations convey any difference in *meaning* (not even a subtle nuance, so far as I'm concerned). Nor does *formal/informal* come into it.

Finally, here are links to three NGrams showing how [doubt](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20doubt%20that%20he,I%20doubt%20he&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) is falling into line with [think](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20think%20that%20he,I%20think%20he&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) and [expect](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20expect%20that%20he,I%20expect%20he&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), in terms of not normally being followed by a superfluous *"that"*.

Answer (score 1):

My version would be something like this:

> Your question is very broad, and I'm not sure if/whether it is answerable.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. All you've done is irrelevantly swapped *am not sure* for *doubt*, and tacitly ruled out "that". You give no reason for discarding one of OP's three suggestions, nor do you say anything about the relative merits of the remaining two.

Comment: You are right @FumbleFingers but since I'm not a grammar expert, I didn't want to state something that might not be true. So I just gave my suggestion of how it could sound a lot better based on my experience dealing with native speakers for years.

Comment: Arguably then it should have been posted as a comment. I wouldn't want to discourage people who aren't "grammar experts" from posting answers (I'm not one myself, to be honest), but it's difficult to see what future visitors will  learn from this "answer", and (no slur on you) I don't understand why at least four people have chosen to upvote it.

Comment: I see this website as a lighter version of http://english.stackexchange.com so that's why I posted as an answer and not as a commment. If the same question was asked there, I'd surely post it as a comment.

Comment: It all depends what you mean by "lighter". Arguably in some cases it's "more okay" on ELU to mention, say, relatively uncommon usages that might be seen as pointlessly distracting detail on ELL. But I don't think the basic principles of "what constitutes an answer" should be more relaxed here. If a specific question is asked, any and all answers should address it - ideally, giving supporting references or reasoning. For example, do you actually *have* any reason for discarding OP's *"that"* from OP's list of alternatives? If so, I think you should give it.

Answer (score 0):

The word *whether* doesn't apply here because of a pattern which is consistent [*wh-* words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word).

We cannot doubt a [*wh-* proposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement#Wh-islands). These are all wrong:

- {I doubt / I do not believe / I believe / I think / I'm sure } who will be there.
- {I doubt / I do not believe / I believe / I think / I'm sure } what it is.
- {I doubt / I do not believe / I believe / I think / I'm sure } when he will come.
- {I doubt / I do not believe / I believe / I think / I'm sure } whether it will rain tomorrow.

These are right:

- {I don't know / Tell me / I wonder / I'm not sure} who will be there.
- {I don't know / Tell me / I wonder / I'm not sure} what it is.
- {I don't know / Tell me / I wonder / I'm not sure} when he will come.
- {I don't know / Tell me / I wonder / I'm not sure} whether it will rain tomorrow.

In a nutshell the reason is that, *Wh-* words are embedded questions. For example, by itself, *who will be there* is a question: *Who will be there?*.   And you cannot doubt a question! You can only doubt a statement (such as the answer to a question). A question is itself an expression of doubt.

Also, note how the presence or absence of the word *not* does not make a difference in *I do not believe*. However, the *not* makes a difference in: *I'm not sure*. This is a semantic matter rather than purely syntactic: it has to do with meaning rather than grammar.

Now about *if*. The word *if*, in this situation, is a substitute for *whether* that many modern English speakers use. It can also substitute for *that*, but these two usages are not on the same level. *I wonder if it will rain* (*if* substituting for *whether*) is broadly acceptable and can be used in formal writing, but *I doubt if it is true* (*if* substituting for *that*) is still very colloquial.

The likely reason why *if* instead of *that* is less acceptable is that *if* instead of *whether* serves a useful purpose: it provides economy of expression. *if* is only one syllable and phonetically easier than *whether*. Not to mention that it is two letters instead of seven, in writing.  But the word *that* can be economized by a complete omission: if *that* is troublesome to say or write, you can usually just drop it entirely! So there is no point in replacing it with *if*.  Quite simply, *I doubt it is true*.

Comment: I dispute the claim that *to doubt **whether*** something is true is somehow grammatically "wrong". It may not be so common today, but for over 40 years in C19 it was actually [the most popular choice](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+doubt+there+is%2CI+doubt+if+there+is%2CI+doubt+whether+there+is%2CI+doubt+that+there+is&year_start=1827&year_end=1867&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). No new rules of grammar have been introduced since then which would make this an invalid construction.

Comment: Try [this search](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=doubt+that%2Cdoubt+if%2Cdoubt+whether&year_start=1827&year_end=1867&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) instead. It is less specific.

Comment: But by the very fact of being "less specific", that search term erroneously suggests that *to doubt that* was actually the more common usage during that period! An error caused purely by the fact that the "looser" search pulls in more "false positives" - I just checked the first two pages of results on your link; less than half of them actually involve the word "doubt" being used as a verb, which is our context here. Whereas virtually every single instance in my search will be a genuinely relevant verb usage.